# JAR manifest Class-Path, use folder instead of jar

Tags: java, jar, resources, classpath, classloader

I have the following directory structure

```
--conf
|   |
|   --foo.properties
|
--lib
   |
   --application.jar
```

In my application.jar's `MANIFEST.mf` file I have the following entry: `Class-Path: ../conf/`

In the class inside jar (called by the main method of jar) I try to load the *foo.properties* file as classpath resource using following code

```
URL properties = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("foo.properties");
```

However, the resource couldn't be found from the classpath. Why isn't the Class-Path attribute working in the jar manifest? Have I misunderstood how it affects the application classloader classpath?

I'm running the application with following command

`java -jar application.jar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work. Not sure, whether your `MANIFEST.mf` is formatted properly. I generated mine with Maven and it works. This is how my `MANIFEST.mf` looks like,

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: john.doe
Class-Path: ../conf/
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.9
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_92
Main-Class: com.basaki.misc.clazzpath.FindResource
```

You can find a complete example [here](https://github.com/indrabasak/stackoverflow-indra/tree/master/miscellaneous-examples).